# Bounding Fourier transform of $L^{1}$ functions that don't vanish at infinity.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

It is fairly easy to show using integration by parts that if $f\in L^{1}$
  is differentiable and $f^{'}\in L^{1}$
  then under assumption that $f$
  also vanishes at infinity one has $\sup_{\xi\in\mathbb{R}}\left|\xi\hat{f}\left(\xi\right)\right|\leq\left\Vert f^{'}\right\Vert _{1}$
 , this is evident using integration by parts $$\hat{f^{'}}\left(\xi\right)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-i\xi x}f^{'}\left(x\right)dx=e^{-i\xi x}f\left(x\right)\vert_{-\infty}^{\infty}+\int_{\mathbb{R}}i\xi e^{-i\xi x}f\left(x\right)dx=i\xi\hat{f}\left(\xi\right)$$
 My question is, can you forgo the assumption that $f$
  vanishes at infinity and still get this bound? I couldn't even come up with an example of an integrable function that doesn't vanish at infinity and also has an integrable derivative.

Comment: if $f \in L^1$ and is continuous then $f $ vanishes at $\infty$ (in other words, $\int_{x+a}^{x+b} |f(t)| dt$ vanishes when $|x| \to \infty$)

Comment: Continuity enough isn't sufficient to ensure $f\in L^{1}$ vanishes at infinity, take for example $cos(x^2)$. Uniform continuity however as stated in the answer below does guarantee it.

Comment: why do you think $|\cos(x^2)| \in L^1$ ?

Comment: Oops, you're right, it is only conditionally integrable and not absolutely integrable. My bad. There is an example though of a strictly non-negative function that I think is $L^{1}$ and doesn't vanish at infinity, it appears in Counterexamples in Analysis on page 45. Or at least it's an example of a continuous function with an improper integral on $[1,\infty)$ that doesn't vanish at $+\infty$.

Comment: ok $|\cos(x)|^x$ or something like that is a counter-example, what I meant was $f \in L^1 \implies g(x) = \int_{x+a}^{x+b} |f(t)|dt$ vanishes when $|x| \to \infty$, so continuity is not enough but uniform continuity is, as probably many other types of strong continuity

Comment: Yep, that is indeed true :)

Comment: Couldn't you simply claim that: $|f(x)|  = \left| \int_{-\infty}^{x}f'(x)dx\right| \leq  \int_{-\infty}^{x}|f'(x)|dx $, now  $\int_{-\infty}^{x}|f'(x)|dx \to 0$ as $x\to -\infty$, consequently $f(x) \to 0$ as $x\to -\infty$. Set $g(x)= f(-x)$ same proof work for $x\to +\infty$ since $g'(x)$ is integrable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To help with your "I couldn't even …" comment: There's a good reason you couldn't; it's impossible. We need the following lemma:

Lemma: Suppose $f\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ and $\int_\infty^\infty|f'| < \infty.$ Then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R.$

Proof: Let $\epsilon>0.$ Then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $0<y-x<\delta$ implies $\int_x^y|f'| < \epsilon.$ Therefore for such $x,y$ we have

$$|f(y)-f(x)| = |\int_x^yf'| \le \int_x^y|f'| < \epsilon.$$

That proves the lemma.

It's therefore impossible to find $f\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ with $f,f'\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ and $f\not \in C_0(\mathbb R).$ Why? Because the lemma shows $f$ is uniformly continuous, and a uniformly continuous function that doesn't vanish at $\infty$ can't belong to $L^1.$ I'll leave that last part to you for now.

Comment: Lovely! thanks so much :)
I already knew that $L^{1}$ functions which are uniformly continuous must vanish at infinity, I didn't think about showing that integrable derivative implies uniform continuity.